# Oracle SQL: Fetch duplicate rows with one different column and have conditions on the result

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

My table data looks like this

```
_______________________
testid rulekey result
_______________________
1234  | abc_123 | Test Pass   
1234  | abc_123 | Test Fail    
1234  | abc_123 | Missing Data    
5678  | xyz_599 | Test Pass    
5678  | xyz_599 | Test Pass    
5678  | xyz_599 | Missing Data
```

I want the result to just return  unique testid and rulekey (and several columns not represented here) and have a condition to return the result i.e if even one row of the duplicate rows has Test Fail, its Test Fail similarly if its Missing Data for one test and pass for others overall result is still Missing Data.

Can someone please help with the query?

```
1234 abc_123 Test Fail
5678 xyz_599 Missing Data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using analytical function `row_number` as following:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*, 
        row_number() over 
        (partition by testid, rubekey 
        order by case result 
                 when 'Test Fail' then 1 
                 when 'Missing Data' then 2 
                 else 3 end) 
        as rn
From your_table t)
Where rn = 1
```

Cheers!!